# httr GET SSL connect error

Tags: r, ssl, curl, httr

I'm stuck in an error regarding CURL and SSL and I don't have a clue about what is going on.

I've updated every possible package and succeed to get responses from other HTTPS requests. I tried on Windows 7 and 10.

What is wrong with this code?

```
u <-"https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Aplicacoes/SSL/ATCTA/CPF/ConsultaPublica.asp"
curl::curl_fetch_memory(u,  new_handle(verbose=T))


* timeout on name lookup is not supported
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 161.148.231.100...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.receita.fazenda.gov.br (161.148.231.100) port 443 (#3)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/Users/athos.damiani/Documents/R/R-3.3.2/etc/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.receita.fazenda.gov.br:443 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 3
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(u, new_handle(verbose = T)) : 
  SSL connect error
```

My sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] curl_2.3   httr_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.2.0    tools_3.3.2
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can try `curl::curl_fetch_memory(u,  new_handle(verbose=TRUE, ssl_verifyhost=FALSE, ssl_verifypeer=FALSE))` (which is *very* insecure) but as @froderik points out, there are other issues with that site since the result of that call is `Failure when receiving data from the peer`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Tried it, but no luck. One new info: I managed to fetch it in command line (outside R). Any hint?

Comment: When I try it on the command-line with `curl` (no options) I get the SSL cert warning. When I use `curl --insecure` (to mimic the options I suggests in R) I get HTML but I also get `curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806` at the very end.

Comment: Unfortunately `RCurl::getURL("https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Aplicacoes/SSL/ATCTA/CPF/ConsultaPublica.asp", .opts=list(ssl.verifypeer=0, failonerror=0))` also does the same thing.

Comment: Well, that's weird. My curl doesn't recognize the -insecure parameter. I'm using curl 7.51.0.

Comment: `--insecure` (mis-paste)

Comment: getURL gave me the html! This is something lol, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not related to r since curl reports that

```
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.receita.fazenda.gov.br:443
```

on that URL. So there is a generic problem with the SSL cert you'll need to solve.

Comment: Thanks in advance, Froderik.
After a simple test, now I think is R related because when I ran
"curl url" in the terminal directly it worked with no error.
With this information, any toughs about what is causing this error inside R?
regards

Comment: I don't knwo anything about how R works with https but the normal culprit in cases like this is missing rootcertificates necessary to initiates the SSL handshake. Curl obviously got them then. (Also - since you can reach it with curl and I can not there is something more to it.)